# Smoothness of the Solution of a Two-Point Boundary Value Problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given a two-point boundary value problem:
$$
\begin{cases}
-u''(x) = f(x,u(x)), \space \space \space \space \space \space x\in (0,1),\\
u(0) = \alpha,\space u(1) = \beta
\end{cases}
$$
for a given $f \in C([0,1] \times \mathbb{R}):[0,1] \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$

Suppose $u \in C([0,1]) \cap C^2((0,1)$ satisfies the BVP.

I am asked to show that $u \in C^2([0,1])$.

Attempt:

By the ODE in the BVP, we see that:
$$
u''(0) = -\lim_{x \to 0}f(x,u(x))\\
u''(1) = -\lim_{x \to 1}f(x,u(x))
$$

Thus, $u \in C^2([0,1])$ (qed)

However, I don't think my solution is correct.

Comment: What properties of $f$ are known? It has to be at least continuous?

Comment: @LutzLehmann My bad $f \in C([0,1] \times \mathbb{R})$

Comment: Now contemplate that you could extend the domain of $f$ while $f$ stays continuous (many constructions are possible). Then apply what you know about maximal domains of ODE solutions to conclude that $[0,1]$ is not the maximal domain for the extended ODE.

Comment: I don't think I have enough knowledge to understand your hints.